# 3DLBP and GLBP detectors for Depth images Implementation

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, lbph-algorithm

I'm interessting on features extraction from depth images. I have found 3DLBP and GLBP detectors. But i can not found there implementation (Matlab, opencv,...)

I would like to know, if there is any implementation for LBP descriptor for depth images in opencv or c++.
The referenced works are:
3DLBP: Huang, Y., Wang, Y., Tan, T.: Combining statistics of geometrical and correlativefeatures for 3D face recognition. 
And Gradient LBP: Tri Huynh, Rui Min, Jean-Luc Dugelay, "An Efficient LBP-based Descriptor for Facial Depth Images applied to Gender Recognition using RGB-D Face Data," in ACCV Workshop on Computer Vision with Local Binary Pattern Variants 2012, Daejeon, Korea, November 2012.
If any one can help me and answer me.
many thanks

Comment: LBP is fairly simple. See an example here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36484-local-binary-patterns

Have you tried contacting the authors for the 3D version?

Comment: I don't not sure if the 3D LBP is implemented in this toolbox.

Comment: For authors, i didn't contact him :)